# Column Value Reporting String Array C

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

I made this sample 2d array of strings

```
char *strings[][4] = {{"Sport", "gender", "country", "medal"},
                      {"Cycling", "Womens", "China", "first"}, 
                      {"Swimming", "Womens", "China", "second"}, 
                      {"Swimming", "Womens", "Indonesia", "third"}, 
                      {"Cycling", "Womens", "New Zealand", "second"},   
                      {"Cycling", "Womens", "New Zealand", "third"}, 
                      {"Swimming", "Womens", "New Zealand", "first"}}
```

Which has already been pre-sorted based on columns `3 1`, whereby it was sorted first by country(column 3) and then when that column had ties, then it was sorted based on sports(column 1).

I am trying to do some simple hierarchical reporting, with headers at the top, something like this:

```
Country
    Sport   Count
-----------------
China
    Cycling     1
    Swimming    1

Indonesia
    Swimming    1

New Zealand
    Cycling     2
    Swimming    1
```

Where the data is grouped firstly by the countries(column 3), then counts of the sports for each country are taken, where no repeats for any sport must occur in each country.

I also want to make this diverse, let's say the array is pre sorted on columns `3 1 2`, then this would look like this:

```
{{"Sport", "gender", "country", "medal"},
 {"Cycling", "Womens", "China", "first"}, 
 {"Swimming", "Womens", "China", "second"}, 
 {"Swimming", "Womens", "Indonesia", "third"}, 
 {"Cycling", "Womens", "New Zealand", "second"},   
 {"Cycling", "Womens", "New Zealand", "third"}, 
 {"Swimming", "Womens", "New Zealand", "first"}}
```

but then the hierarchical reporting would look a bit different:

```
China
    Cycling
        Womens 1
    Swimming
        Womens 1

Indonesia
    Swimming
        Womens 1

New Zealand
    Cycling
        Womens 2
    Swimming
        Womens 1
```

I have already got the sorting figured out, my issue is just getting this sort of hierarchical reporting to work.

For the column specifications, I have just been using command line arguments, and my program looks like this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 10

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *strings[][4] = {{"Sport", "gender", "country", "medal"},
                          {"Cycling", "Womens", "China", "first"}, 
                          {"Swimming", "Womens", "China", "second"}, 
                          {"Swimming", "Womens", "Indonesia", "third"}, 
                          {"Cycling", "Womens", "New Zealand", "second"},   
                          {"Cycling", "Womens", "New Zealand", "third"}, 
                          {"Swimming", "Womens", "New Zealand", "first"}};

    int count, start_index, i;
    int columns[MAXSIZE];

    /* printing command line args out */
    for (i  = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", columns[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this sort of hierarchical reporting? Is there some sort of special algorithm I need to implement for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've mentioned that you hand-sorted this data, but until you're willing to take on other data structures (e.g. graphs of strings, rather than arrays of strings) you won't get anywhere without dynamic sorting... Bear with me for a moment, I'll take you the *quick* way:

> Let's just reinvent the `qsort` whee... wait! LET'S USE `qsort`!

Indeed, it is a shame that we have a culture of reinventing wheels before we research the existing ones.

You'll probably want a comparison function for each row. These will form the criteria to sort upon. In their most basic form, they might look something like this:

```
int sport_compare(void const *x, void const *y) {
    typedef char const * const row[4];
    row *fu = x, *ba = y;
    return strcmp(fu[0], ba[0]);
}

int gender_compare(void const *x, void const *y) {
    typedef char const * const row[4];
    row *fu = x, *ba = y;
    return strcmp(fu[1], ba[1]);
}
```

... and so on.

> How can I use these to reinvent the `qsort` wheel?

```
#define nelem(array) (sizeof array / sizeof *array)
qsort(array, nelem(array), sizeof *array, country_compare);
```

Now `array` is sorted by country... are you following?

```
qsort(array, nelem(array), sizeof *array, gender_compare);
```

... and so on.

---

Now that you know how to resort your array with virtually any condition in just five or six lines of code, you can put more thought into the comparison functions to solve your actual problem (that is, the heirarchy you desire)..

For example, when two rows are equal in sport, are they also equal in everything else? You might want to think about modifying `sport_compare` to inspect the rest of the columns when the two columns have the same sport... For example:

```
int sport_compare(void const *x, void const *y) {
    typedef char const * const row[4];
    row *fu = x, *ba = y;
#   define maybe_return(condition) do { int c = (condition); if (c) { return c; } } while (0)
    maybe_return(strcmp(fu[0], ba[0]));
    maybe_return(strcmp(fu[1], ba[1]));
    maybe_return(strcmp(fu[2], ba[2]));
    return strcmp(fu[3], ba[3]);
}
```

This still sorts by sport primarily, but will also consider other columns in the comparison if necessary, which will give you all of the women from the same country and sport grouped together so you can eliminate duplicates easily for example...

For four columns there are a total of sixteen permutations in the order of columns. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to write the ones that interest you most.

Comment: You might also (eventually) be interested in naming your structure members, e.g. `struct entry { sport sport; gender gender; etc... }`

Answer (score 3):

If you sort the array and use a for loop then you will get almost exactly the output you need:

```
China 
    Cycling first
    Swimming second
 Indonesia 
    Swimming third
 New Zealand 
    Cycling second
    Swimming first
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv ) {
    char *a[][4] = {{"Sport",    "gender", "country",     "medal"},
                          {"Cycling",  "Womens", "China",       "first"},
                          {"Swimming", "Womens", "China",       "second"},
                          {"Swimming", "Womens", "Indonesia",   "third"},
                          {"Cycling",  "Womens", "New Zealand", "second"},
                          {"Cycling",  "Womens", "New Zealand", "third"},
                          {"Swimming", "Womens", "New Zealand", "first"}};

    int count, start_index, i;
    int columns[MAXSIZE];

    /* Storing command line args in array */
    start_index = 1;
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        columns[i] = atoi(argv[start_index]);
        count++;
        start_index++;
    }
    char * temp;
    char * temp1;
    for(int j=1;j<6;j++)
    {
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            if(a[0][i]>a[0][i+1])
            {
                temp=a[0][i];
                a[0][i]=a[0][i+1];
                a[0][i+1]=temp;

                temp1 = a[1][i];
                a[1][i] = a[1][i+1];
                a[1][i+1]=temp1;
            }
        }
    }
    char * country ="";
    char * sport = "";
    for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) {
        if (strcmp(country, a[i][2])) printf("%s \n", a[i][2]);
        if (strcmp(country, a[i][2]) || strcmp(sport, a[i][0])) {
            country = a[i][2];
            sport = a[i][0];
            printf("\t%s %s", a[i][0], a[i][3]);
            printf("\n ");

            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may give you some ideas. The function will need a depth for the number of columns to consider ( 1, 2...). If those columns match, increment the count. Otherwise print the count and reset the count to 1. `col[]` is the sort order for the columns. This assumes that row zero is the column headings instead of data.

```
void print_array(char str[][COLS][MAX_CH], int nrows, int ncols, int depth, int col[]) {
    int i, j;
    int count = 1;
    int width = 0;
    int same = 0;
    int wide = 0;
    int widest = 0;
    int order[COLS] = { 0};

    for (i = 1; i < nrows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            if ( strlen ( str[i][j]) > widest) {
                widest = strlen ( str[i][j]);//the widest element
            }
        }
    }
    widest += 2;

    for (i = 1; i < nrows; i++) {
        same = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            if ( j < depth) {
                if ( strcmp ( str[i][order[j] - 1], str[i - 1][order[j] - 1]) == 0) {
                    same++;//number of considered columns that are the same
                }
                else {
                    break;//stop on the first difference
                }
            }
        }
        if ( same == depth) {
            count++;//all considered columns are the same, add to count
        }
        else {
            if ( i > 1) {
                printf ( "%*d\n", widest - wide, count);//print the alligned count on last printed column but not on first iteration
            }
            count = 1;
            if ( same == 0 && i > 1) {
                printf ( "\n");//print extra newline when no columns are the same, after first iteration
            }
        }
        if ( count == 1) {//print the columns
            for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
                if ( ( same - j) > 0 && ( strcmp (str[i][order[j] - 1], str[i - 1][order[j] - 1]) ==  0)) {
                    continue;//skip columns that are the same
                }
                if ( j < depth) {//the columns considered by depth
                    wide = strlen ( str[i][order[j] - 1]);
                    width = wide + j * 4;//for leading spaces
                    printf("%*s", width, str[i][order[j] - 1]);//print aligned column
                    if ( j < depth - 1) {
                        printf ( "\n");//print a newline except for last col so count can be printed later
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf ( "%*d\n", widest - wide, count);//print count on last row
}
```